# Color is not working with Adding legend in PyQtGraph

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqtgraph

I am trying to add legend in PyQtGraph plot but I am unable to add the color to it. 
According to the [docs](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/graphicsItems/plotdataitem.html), it should be working. My code is below:

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication([])   
win = pg.GraphicsWindow(title="Simulation")
p = win.addPlot()
style1 = pg.PlotDataItem(pen=None,symbol='o',symbolBrush=["m"])
style2 = pg.PlotDataItem(pen=None,symbol='o',symbolBrush=["r"])
legend = p.addLegend()
legend.addItem(style2,' Majority')
legend.addItem(style1,' Minority')
sys.exit(QtGui.QApplication.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
import pyqtgraph as pg          

import numpy as np

# define the data
theTitle = "pyqtgraph plot"
y  = [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20]
y2 = [0,1,2,4,12,14,16,17,14,22]
x  = range(0,10)

# create plot
plt = pg.plot()
plt.showGrid(x=True, y=True)
plt.addLegend()

# set properties
plt.setLabel('left', 'Value', units='V')
plt.setLabel('bottom', 'Time', units='s')
plt.setXRange(0, 10)
plt.setYRange(0, 20)
plt.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph plot')

# plot
c1 = plt.plot(x, y,  pen='b', symbol='x', symbolPen='b', symbolBrush=0.2, name='_blue')
c2 = plt.plot(x, y2, pen='r', symbol='o', symbolPen='r', symbolBrush=0.2, name='_red')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: How would you fill the color in brush?